# Asus ME302KL tablet halts on loading

Tags: bootloader, system-error, system-freeze

I have a problem with my Asus MeMO Pad ME302KL

It halts on loading screen - Asus logo and loading spinner and loads forever, until the battery goes off completely.

Holding the power button for 10 seconds reboots it.
Holding the reset button (the one in the hole) for 10 seconds just reboots it.

Tried to enter service menus:

1. Holding the power button and volume down - after 10 seconds the tablet shuts down, after 5 more seconds shows system information. Asus logo and some text on the left. Does not react to any actions, except for holding the power button for 10 seconds and goes to reboot.
2. Holding the power button and volume up - after 10 seconds the tablet shuts down, after 5 more seconds shows "service menu". First for half a second there appears a standing android with spinning blue thing in front of him, and after half a second there appears a lying android with open bonnet and a red exclamation mark and nothing else on the screen. Does not react to any actions, except for holding the power button for 10 seconds and goes to reboot.

**UPD:** Tried to hold the reset button while on the "service screens" and it just goes to reboot after 10 seconds. Also have removed the SIM and SD cards.

**UPD2:** Before the lethal shut down I've installed a couple of games, ~5 I guess. I'm not sure, if it installed any updates, at least it did not ask m e about it.

**UPD3:** With use of fastboot re-installed this system https://mega.co.nz/#!QFEFFRCR!XV2tziLIueLET2aBXWBaXUp5qY5vw7vS740yYxgKO7M and absolutely nothing has changed :(

Comment: When did this start happening? Was it after a system update?

Comment: It could. I'm not sure, if it installed any updates. At least it did not ask me anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the combination to enter the recovery mode. Holding the power button and volume up - after 10 seconds the tablet shuts down, after 5 more seconds shows "service menu". First for half a second there appears a standing android with spinning blue thing in front of him, and after half a second there appears a lying android with open bonnet and a red exclamation mark (error) and nothing else on the screen.

Then you have to hold the power again and press the volume up - the menu appears.

Cleared the cache and device started normally. That's pretty weird, as I've re-installed the whole system and cleaned the cache with fastloader. But it works now :)